# Can't access unsaved children in before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's my model:

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveUUID::UUID
  belongs_to :organisation
  has_many :receipt_line_items
  before_validation :calculate_total_cost  

  private

   def calculate_total_cost
     self.total_cost = self.receipt_line_items.sum(:cost)
   end
end
```

I've tested and `calculate_total_cost` does run, but the `total_cost` field is unchanged in my database. The field is a Decimal 12,2, and so is the `cost` field in `receipt_line_items`.

I later found out that it *is* working, but the `receipt_line_items` get saved automagically with the `receipt`, which turns out to be *after* `calculate_total_cost` . In other words, none of the line items are saved when the db is queried for their costs.

**Is there a way to access unsaved children's attributes?**

Answer (score 0):

use the `write_attribute` method so something like `write_attribute(:total_cost,self.receipt_line_items.sum(:cost))` hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to access unsaved children, but in the end I didn't need to.

This was a chicken-egg situation—I needed the children to get the total cost for the parent, and I needed the parent for the children to reference.

But this was bad design. I have the individual costs in the children, I shouldn't store the total in the database as well, that's duplicating information. Now I don't store the total, and simply calculate it from the children when I need to access it.